# Receive params from child component functions

Tags: reactjs

I have 2 components parent and child in separate .js files and I'm trying to get the value of the select component in the child from the parent.

**Child component**

```
export default function ChildComponent(props) {

  return (
    <Select value="0" onChange={(event) => props.onClick(event.target.value)}>
      <MenuItem value={0}>Edit</MenuItem>
      <MenuItem value={1}>Save</MenuItem>
    </Select>
  );

}
```

**Parent component which renders Child components**

```
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

  function alertValue(param) {
    alert(param);
  }

ReactDOM.render(<ChildComponent
    onClick={() => alertValue()} />, document.querySelector("#somediv"));
```

When the value of the select component is changed in a child, it does invoke the reset timer in parent component however the value is undefined, what am I missing here? I have seen other solutions based on class, but is it possible to do without a class?

Comment: Please see [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed the value from child component to props, but you are not passing it in the function in parent component. so parent component is not getting the value.

```
  import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

function alertValue(param) {
    alert(param);
    }

ReactDOM.render(<ChildComponent
    onClick={() => alertValue()} />, document.querySelector("#somediv"));
```

This is wrong, you are not passing params here in parent component

Change the above code to

```
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
 function alertValue(param) {
    alert(param);
    }

ReactDOM.render(<ChildComponent
    onClick={(e) => alertValue(e)} />, document.querySelector("#somediv"));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you don't pass any value to `alertValue` function

```
<ChildComponent
    onClick={() => alertValue()} />
```

You need to pass value to `alertValue` function

```
<ChildComponent
    onClick={(value) => alertValue(value)} />
```